# Is Samsung Galaxy S II rear camera Gorilla Glass too?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, camera

is Samsung Galaxy S II rear camera Gorilla Glass too?

It sticks out a little above the case, so I would like to know if it's durable enough not to need to buy special case which, obviously, makes the phone thicker.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, interesting question!

Comment: hit it with a hammer and see what happens :). DON'T REALLY DO THAT! But that is an interesting question. I would actually doubt that it is. since it is such a small surface area, I dont think they would pay for the cost of gorilla glass.

Comment: I'll answer myself. It isn't. I have observed tiny scratches already :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not, my Galaxy S II already has a lot of little scratches on the camera "glass", and unlike in my old HTC Desire phone, GSII doesn't have extra "glass" in the back plate to protect the actual lens. So when it gets scratched I cannot just exchange the backplate :(.

I treat my phone very gently, so I'm very surprised to see the lens having some many little scratches :(. Clearly in GSII the lens is way too unprotected and near the surface when you place it on flat surface.

As a extra step, I bought case-mate "though" case to add a bit more space between the lens and flat surface. Although the lens is scratched all the pictures seem to be just fine. Phew...

Answer (score 3):

Yeah it's **not** , have seen scratches on a friends GSII rear facing camera myself.